# Bitrix24 On-Premise site failing to load the pages with error message. This site can’t be reached. connection refused

Tags: apache, nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite, bitrix

I am failing to access the Bitrix24 On-Premise site. When I enter http://intranet/ the site is redirecting to http://intranet:8890 and then gives  an error "This site can’t be reached" connection refused

Similarly, if I try to access an old bookmarked url for example http://intranet/stream I am being redirected to http://intranet:8890/?back_url=%2Fstream%2F and then the "This site can’t be reached" connection refused is displayed.

Thanking you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like u've turned ntlm auth on, but its not configured well.

```
    <?
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = '/home/bitrix/www/';
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS",true);
define('BX_NO_ACCELERATOR_RESET', true);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");

if(!CModule::IncludeModule('ldap'))
  return false;


CLdapUtil::UnSetBitrixVMAuthSupport(true);

echo 'Ntlm auth off';

?>
```

You can paste it into your index.php. And open it in browser. After that, delete the pasted code and everything is gonna work fine.